# Removing row refresh page jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing an issue with my jquery. I have used jQuery to add controls to table, along with a remove button to remove that particular row in table. here is my code on how i am creating controls in table.

**HTML**

```
<table id="controls" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
</table>
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
```

my jquery code looks like this

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
        var field = $("#field").val();
                var year = new Date().getFullYear()
                var DDL_fromProfession = "<select name='ParametersFromProf' id='DDL_FromProYear'>";
                for (var i = 1950; i <= year; i++) {
                    DDL_fromProfession += "<option text='" + i + "' value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
                }
                DDL_fromProfession += "</select>";
                var DDL_ToProfession = "<select name='ParametersToProf'  id='DDL_ToProYear'>";
                for (var i = 1950; i <= year; i++) {
                    DDL_ToProfession += "<option text='" + i + "' value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
                }
                DDL_ToProfession += "</select>";

                var newRow1 = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: large; color: #212121;' height='35px'>from"
                 + DDL_fromProfession + " to " + DDL_ToProfession + "</td></tr>"
                 + "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size:large;color:#212121;' height'35px'>"
                 + "<input type='checkbox' name='chkbx_CurrPro' value='" + k + "'>I currently work here</input>";
                newRow1 += "<br/><button id='btn_rmv'>Remove</button>";


                var input = "<input name='parameters' id='field' type='text' />";
                var input1 = "<input name='parametersCompany' id='field' type='text'/>"

                //var inputCurrent="<input name='Current' id='Currfield' type='hidden'/>"

                var newRow = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: x-large; color: #212121;' height='35px'>"
                 + input + " at " + input1 + "</td></tr>";
                $('#controls').append(newRow);
                $('#controls').append(newRow1);
            });
        });
```

to remove last row i am using. 
**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $("#controls").delegate("#btn_rmv", "click", function() {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                return false;
            });
        });
```

clicking on remove button refresh the page and remove all the rows that i have added instead of last one.
NOTE: What i ahve digged out is `.delegate` is server side and it refresh the page. i am unable to remove last row with `$("#btn_rmv").click(function()` on my page

Please point me to right direction.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in question does not work as `k` is not defined, as used in the line

```
value='" + k + "'
```

If this error is corrected then the next problem is that you are creating multiple elements with the same `id`, as seen here

```
newRow1 += "<br/><button id='btn_rmv'>Remove</button>";
```

which in invalid HTML and will cause problems for jQuery in finding the element with the *unique* `id`.

By changing `k` for `0` and changing the `id` to a `class`, the *remove* code will **only** remove the *current row* with the button on. I assume that you really want to remove that row and also the preceding 2 rows.

```
$('#controls').delegate('.btn_rmv', 'click', function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1 // as nth-child is 1-based indexing
    $('#controls tr:nth-child(n+' + (index - 2) + '):nth-child(-n+' + index + ')').remove(); // remove 3 rows
    return false
});
```

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5VudB/)

Please note that since jQuery 1.7, [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is superseded by [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) so the updated function is:

```
$('#controls').on('click', '.btn_rmv', function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1
    $('#controls tr:nth-child(n+' + (index - 2) + '):nth-child(-n+' + index + ')').remove();
    return false
});
```

Comment: Thanks for Sorting up my code. But problem is when i click on remove button, my page refreshes and i lost values written in text box plus if i have added multiple rows using add button. clicking on any row removes all the rows created using add button.

Comment: The page is refreshing because of JavaScript errors. Fixing those should stop the page refreshing. My answer and demo offer a solution to only removing one entry and not all of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience: I was using Google Chrome and it would refresh the page everytime I called a function. You will have to return false. My problem was when I called a function from an element using "onclick". When I called the function from onclick I had to include the "return false;":

```
onclick="return false; functionName()"
```

Try this and see if it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
        /* YOUR CODE */

        return false;
    });
});
```

Or this and see if it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
        /* YOUR CODE */            
    });

    return false;
});
```

Sorry my Javascript is not very good :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way..

```
   var RowCount = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
            RowCount = RowCount + 1;

            var newRow1 = "<tr id='tr" + RowCount + "'><td align='center' style='font-size: large; color: #212121;' height='35px'>from"
             + DDL_fromProfession + " to " + DDL_ToProfession + "</td></tr>"
             + "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size:large;color:#212121;' height'35px'>"
             + "<input type='checkbox' name='chkbx_CurrPro' value='" + k + "'>I currently work here</input>";

            newRow1 += "<br/><button id='btn_rmv' onclick='RemoveRow(" + RowCount + ")'>Remove</button>";
        });

    });

    function RemoveRow(RowID) {
        $('#RemoveRow' + RowID).remove();
    }
```

Comment: I have added RowCount as id for each tr which is incremented in each row add. On removing row pass the RowCount to remove function. So you can exactly remove particular row

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are hooking up the remove click handler on `$(document).ready`.

On document.ready, the remove buttons do not yet exist (since they are generated dynamically when clicking 'Add', after the document.ready code has run). That's why `$("#btn_rmv").click(function()...` is not working.

So, after dynamically inserting a remove button in the `$("#btnAdd").click` event, you explicitly have to add a click handler to it.

EDIT:

If you generate your remove buttons with a unique id (eg. btn_rmv_1, btn_rmv_2, etc), you can add the following to your Add-handler (after appending the new button to the DOM):

```
$('#btn_rmv_1').click(removeButtonFunction);
```